# Batik (1.8) SVG, Enabling Mouse Interaction with Graphics Nodes

Tags: java, svg, batik

Trying to enable mouse interaction with the `SVGDom` via a `JSVGCanvas` instance. I've seen the advice to simply add an `EventListener` to a specific node, such as

```
myNode.addEventListener("mouseover", myListener, true);
```

I have done that, but I am not getting any events fired. I've also tried it with the "click" event. Nothing seems to be working.

I am able to render SVG documents (even fairly complex ones), via the `setSVGDocument(doc)` method. I've also called:

```
setDocumentState(JSVGCanvas.ALWAYS_DYNAMIC)
```

all over the place, especially before calling `setSVGDocument`. I'm not getting any sort of mouse feedback via the rendered SVG. Is there a way of testing that the interactions are happening at a low level? Does one have to register one of those mouse `Interactor`s to enable mouse-actions? Also, does the `SVGDOMImplementation` version matter? I'm not using the `SVG12DOMImplemenation`, but the earlier/standard one.

Advice very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can show this question :

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271972/event-clic-with-dom-batik-recovery-the-use-tag-which-refers-a-symbol][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271972/event-clic-with-dom-batik-recovery-the-use-tag-which-refers-a-symbol