# Adding an element to a DOM document with batik

Tags: java, dom, svg, batik

Good evening,

My problem is when adding an element (rectangle) to my DOM document.

The addition is done as follows:

Creating an element rect light blue / fluo

```
Node node = doc.createElement("rect");
Element elem = (Element)node;
elem.setAttribute("fill", obj.getColor());
```

Contained in a group of elements g

```
Node newZone = doc.createElement("g");
Element elemZone = (Element)newZone;
elemZone.setAttribute("id", zone);
```

Adding the element rect to the element g

```
elemZone.appendChild(elem);
```

Adding to the document

```
doc.getElementById(idUse).appendChild(elemZone);
```

Updating the document JSVGCanvas (which allows the display svg)

```
svg.setDocument(doc);
```

So also weird as it may seem, the change is taken into account, because when I save the document and displays the file, I see the change.

But nothing in the application is updated.

Also, I added an element (symbol + use) following the same process.
JSVGCanvas and update the document is well considered and also visible.

Thank you in advance for your help ...

Remarks:
- Repaint tested np times.
- Launching the application with the document: The rectangle appears good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG elements must be created in the SVG namespace so replace

```
Node node = doc.createElement("rect");
```

by

```
Node node = doc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
```

Same with the `<g>` element. Serialising and unserialising the document will fix the namespace problem which is why you don't see it on reload.

For Batik you must also call

```
jsvgCanvas.setDocumentState(JSVGCanvas.ALWAYS_DYNAMIC);
```

before loading the content too, and make all changes in the [update manager's](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/bridge/UpdateManager.html) thread.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer! I'll tested it this evening. I'm sorry if I'm wrong, but you'd have an idea for this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271972/event-clic-with-dom-batik-recovery-the-use-tag-which-refers-a-symbol